# JSONObject getstring removes the zero from string

Tags: java, android, json, getstring

I'm trying to get numerical values that start with `0s` from a `JSONObject`. The problem is the method converts the string into a double. Example:

JSONObject:

```
{
  "LATITUDE1":41,
  "LATITUDE2":06962
}
```

When I use

```
String lat2 = object.getString("LATITUDE2");
```

the String `lat2` is displayed as `6962.0`. How can I make it so that the string is displayed as it is in the json file (as `06962`)?

I will then need to concatenate the two values and add a dot in between them to get a decimal number such as `41.06962` that's why I need to get the values as strings.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried "LATITUDE1":"41", "LATITUDE2":"06962" ?

Answer (score 6):

If it's a string let it be a string:

```
{
  "LATITUDE1":"41",
  "LATITUDE2":"06962"
}
```

Comment: The problem with that: I don't have a control over the object. It is sent to me from a colleague and I can't change it because there will be other files like this. Also, the file contains 150k of these.

Comment: @user37223 complain to your provider then. As 06962 is not a valid number and it gets automatically converted to 6962.0 or 6962. Otherwise write your own parser. As AFAIK JSON won't help you there either.